# Polynomials question Part (a) and (b)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(a) In this multi-part problem, we will consider this system of simultaneous equations:
$$\begin{array}{r@{~}c@{~}l l}
3x+5y-6z &=&2, & \textrm{(i)} \\
5xy-10yz-6xz &=& -41, & \textrm{(ii)} \\
xyz&=&6. & \textrm{(iii)}
\end{array}$$

Let $a=3x$, $b=5y$, and $c=-6z$.

Determine the monic cubic polynomial in terms of a variable $t$ whose roots are $t=a$, $t=b$, and $t=c$.

(b) Given that $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to the original system of equations, determine all distinct possible values of $x+y$.

I've figured out the polynomial for Part (a), but I'm not sure how to solve Part (b).

Comment: Could you add the working you did to get the polynomial, as it might help in solving the second part?

Comment: If $a=3x$, $b=5y$, and $c=-6z$, we know that $x=a/3, y=b/5, z = -c/6.$ After substituing that into my system of equations, I get $a+b+c=2, ab+bc+ac= - 123, abc = -540.$ Then I got my polynomial (I won't write the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial from part (a) is

$$P(t) : t^3 - 2t^2 -123t + 540 = 0$$

Now, factorizing

$$P(t) = (t-5)(t-9)(t+12) = 0$$

Since it has no repeated roots, the original equation has distinct solutions corresponding to the following 6 match-ups

1. a = 5, b = 9, c = -12 $\implies$ $x+y = \frac{5}{3} + \frac{9}{5}$
2. a = 9, b = 5, c = -12 $\implies x+y = 3 + 1$

and so on.. check for duplicates

Comment: Thank you so much, Dhanvi Sreenivasan!